# prove that if $\lim_{x\to y}f(x)=0$ than there is $f'(a)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$, a differentiable function, where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded open set. Show that, if $\lim_{x\to y}f(x)=0$ for every $y\in\overline U-U$ then there is $a\in U$ such as $f'(a)=0$

I took $F(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in U$ and $F(x)=0$ if $x\in\overline U-U$. Then $F$ is differentiable in $U$ and continuous in the compact $\overline U$. So $F(\overline U)$ is also compact and assumes the maximum and minimum values.

But the maximum and minimum values in a compact don't necessarily imply $F'(x)=0$

There is where I'm stuck. Intuitively, it makes sense that there is $f(x)=0$ for some $x$. But how do I prove it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is a limited open set?

Comment: $f$ is differentialbly therefore continuous.  The condition $\lim_{x\rightarrow y}f(x)=0$ therefore just means $f(y)=0$.  If $f(y)=0$ for two points then the mean value theorem gets you what you want. You just need to extend $f$ to $\bar U$

Comment: @cello it is an open set, that is limited, $U\subset B(0,r)$ for some $r$

Comment: ok, one of the common names for such sets is bounded open set

Comment: Yes, I adjusted that. Bad translation :/

Comment: If $\max F>0$ or $\min F < 0$, then these are attained at interior points and you do have $F'=0$. If $\max F=\min F=0$ then ther's nothing to worry in the first place

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $x_1, x_2 \in\bar U - U$ such that the line segment
$$]x_1,x_2[ \,= \{ (1-t)x_1 + tx_2 : t\in]0,1[ \}$$
is entirely in $U$. (why does it exist?)

Then define $\varphi\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ given by
$$\varphi(t) = F((1-t)x_1 + tx_2).$$
Note that $\varphi$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, differentiable in $]0,1[$ and such that $\varphi(0) = \varphi(1)=0$.

Think about Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: The line is entirely in $U$ only if it is connected, isn't it?

Comment: As $U$ is open, I think one can take the line in a connected component of $U$. Besides, Hagen von Eitzen have solved the problem in a better way.

Comment: Yes, good point. I liked your solution too, thanks

Comment: @rldias I changed my comment because there will exist such a line segment, but you still have the problem that it only shows the directional derivative equals $0$ somewhere on the segment.

Comment: @zhw. No problem, you're absolutely right. This hint doesn't solve the problem. Sorry guys